# second button in my game doesn't colored up

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to JavaFX and I am having a problem.
I want to let the user to be able to color only two buttons each time from the 2X2 buttons, and the 2X2 buttons get reset only after the second get clicked or when the user chose to rest it by the reset button then after that he can choose another 2 buttons, but after clicking on the second one, the second button doesn't get colored and the entier 2X2 buttons got reset, only the first one got colored.

```
public class ColorGame extends Application {

    int onlyTwoSelection = 0;//allowing user to clicke 2 times
    ArrayList<Integer> buttonId = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //Storing the last 2 button clicked Id

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button blankButton[] = new Button[4];//uncolored buttons
        Button reset = new Button("Reset");//Reset all buttons to the first state 
        HBox hbox = new HBox();//Storing Reset
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();
            

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {//This for loop setting all Buttons
            blankButton[i] = new Button();
            blankButton[i].setMinSize(170, 110);
            blankButton[i].setStyle(null);
        }   
            reset.setOnAction(e -> {//Reset all buttons to the first state 

                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    blankButton[i].setStyle(null);
                }
                
        });


        
                gridpane.add(blankButton[0], 0, 0);
                gridpane.add(blankButton[1], 0, 1);
                gridpane.add(blankButton[2], 1, 0);
                gridpane.add(blankButton[3], 1, 1);

                        
        

        


           for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {//finding which buttons get clicked
                final int buttonInd = i;

                blankButton[i].setOnAction(e -> {
                    onlyTwoSelection++;
                    if((onlyTwoSelection<=2&&onlyTwoSelection>0)) {
                        buttonId.add(buttonInd);
                        blankButton[buttonInd].setStyle("-fx-BackGround-color: #ff0000");
                        if(onlyTwoSelection==2) 
                        {
                            blankButton[buttonId.get(0)].setStyle(null);
                            blankButton[buttonId.get(1)].setStyle(null);

                            onlyTwoSelection=0;
                            buttonId.clear();
                        }

                    }





                });
            }   


        hbox.getChildren().addAll(reset);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        gridpane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        borderPane.setCenter(gridpane);
        borderPane.setBottom(hbox);     
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 1000, 700);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ColorGame"); 
        primaryStage.show();

    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

`buttonId` Storing the last 2 buttons.
`onlyTwoSelection` is making sure the user chose two.
`reset` reset the 4X4 buttons.
`buttonInd` is the last button got clicked
the last `for` loob is for finding which button got clicked by the user.

..............

Edit: I think the problem is that this code is getting activated before the user can see the red color, Is there any way to stop or delay it from getting activated for a second?

```
                        if(onlyTwoSelection==2) 
                        {
                            blankButton[buttonId.get(0)].setStyle(null);
                            blankButton[buttonId.get(1)].setStyle(null);

                            onlyTwoSelection=0;
                            buttonId.clear();
                        }
```

Comment: java naming conventions, please

Comment: I think I fix it

Comment: actually no, you didn't ;) .. please do some research to learn java naming conventions - the java tag wiki has a reference afair. If not, just type the term into your favorite search field :) Issue here: field names should start with a lower-case letter

Comment: Thanks, at least I learn something new :)

Comment: good :) .......

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {//finding which buttons get clicked
            final int buttonInd = i;
            blankButton[i].setOnAction(e -> {

                if (onlyTwoSelection < 2) {
                    blankButton[buttonInd].setStyle("-fx-BackGround-color: #ff0000");
                    onlyTwoSelection++;
                } else {
                    onlyTwoSelection = 0;
                    reset.fire();
                    blankButton[buttonInd].setStyle("-fx-BackGround-color: #ff0000");
                    onlyTwoSelection++;
                }
            });
        }
```

Here is the logic.

Comment: yes it's worked but I have to click on the third bouton, and I discovered that the last `if` statement is the root of the problem, Theraticly if I can delay it for a second before it gets activated my code should work as intended

Comment: @Mrkhaled, If this solved your issue, select it as the correct answer. If you now have a new issue after this one was solved, take some time to try to figure it out yourself. If you continue to have problems after you have taken some time to figure it out, come back and ask a new question. Moving questions are not fair to the person who answered your original question.